# cl-who, parenscript, and quotation mark issues generating inline javascript

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot, cl-who, parenscript

So I'm running a parenscript tutorial using the following code:

```
    (defparameter *js-string-delimiter* #\")
    (hunchentoot:define-easy-handler (tutorial1 :uri "/tutorial1") ()
    (cl-who:with-html-output-to-string (s)
                (:html
                 (:head (:title "Parenscript tutorial, example 1"))
                 (:body (:h2 "Parenscript totorial: 1st example")
                    "Please click the link below." :br
                    (:a :href "#" :onclick (parenscript:ps (alert "Hello World!"))
                    "Hello World!")))))
```

The page renders, but the clickable link does not work. When I view the source, I get the following:

```
<html><head><title>Parenscript tutorial, example 1</title></head><body><h2>Parenscript totorial: 1st example</h2>Please click the link below.<br /><a href='#' onclick='alert('Hello World!');'>Hello World!</a></body></html>
```

Which does not work. I need the alert function closed in quotes ", not semi-quotes '. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, my 2c: I like [spinneret](https://github.com/ruricolist/spinneret) better: easier semantic to write macros, html validation (with warnings, handy), can include markdown, a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

OK, after a bunch of looking around, I found that it appears the tutorial is wrong. Instead of using parenscript:ps to generate the code, you should use parenscript:ps-inline to get the quoting correct.

Hope this helps someone else.